# Workflow in CRM Dynamics 365 trigger every day at 10 pm

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I have created a Workflow in CRM Dynamics 365 that it process Entries.

I have 2 entries.

- to be process immediately (Done)
- to be process at 10 pm. (I do not know to do it)

How can I set the process stage to process it at 10pm?

Comment: Did you find any other answer?

Comment: Just use power automate. We are all going to end up there anyway...

Answer (score 3):

To overcome this, you have to use Power Automate (MS Flow) - it has options to [run on schedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks).

Unfortunately Classic WF cannot be configured to run on particular schedule, Microsoft recommending to move to Power Automate for better use cases. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/replace-workflows-with-flows#feature-capability-comparison)

[image]